# How to have text and image in same row using CSS Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have projects on my personal portfolio and I want each row of a grid to have an image pushed to the left or right (odd or even row) with a paragraph description on the opposite side. Basically I want a paragraph and image in-line with each other on the same row. When I do it, the text is above the image, which I do not want. The HTML code is the beginning of the "Projects" section

[image: text over image]

```css
.project-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.odd {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.even {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row odd">
    <p class="project-decription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, similique consequatur expedita natus voluptatum non sint ea vero dignissimos eius. Eos animi, praesentium odit mollitia provident totam repudiandae sapiente cumque. Lorem ipsum, dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique qui, quam dolorem aperiam perferendis minus iure veniam voluptatum molestias, sed non ea obcaecati nemo nisi amet dignissimos illo autem! Aliquam.</p>
    <div class="project-box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="img/whatfoodisthere.png" class="project-image" alt="Project 1">
      <div class="middle">
        <a href="http://whatfoodisthere.com">
          <div class="text">
            Visit Site
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <span class="project-name">Recipe Library</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: your snippet puts everything on a single row.

Comment: It doesn't, that's just the beginning of the snippet. Sorry

Comment: ??  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTbq.jpg can you clarify your question. to me, everything stands on a single row :) paragraph / img(alt text) / link /span

Answer (score 0):

It's cuz you're using the row class from bootstrap. If you remove it, they will be in the same line

Comment: That actually broke it... I want the image and text to be in the same row

Comment: I put the code you provided on a codepen and when I removed the row class, they were on the same line. What exactly is broken? Could you maybe provided your whole code instead of just a part of it?

Edit: just look here https://codepen.io/xstrafez/pen/XWXWPXP